# What are good books or tutorials for learning how to do web design with GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have Photoshop CS5, but I want to switch to GIMP to do basic web design tasks.

Where can I turn to learn how to do web design with GIMP? I'm talking about this like making gradient backgrounds, nav tabs, etc.

Comment: neither GIMP nor Photoshop is a web design tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIMPS's an image editor, not a web designer. Beyond that, if you know Photoshop already, GIMP will be pretty easy to learn. The basic concepts are the same, you'll just have to learn new keyboard shortcuts and where things are hiding in the menus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Marc B; additionally while there might be a good book on gimp (my reflex is to start with O'Reilly) I'm self-taught solely from online documentation. Start with this: http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/

gimp has thought about your question, and they have some answers [here](http://www.gimp.org/books/).